# calling script on few pages

Tags: php, html

I have a website with 50 pages. I have a header.html I include on every page. In the header I link to my external CSS, and the same counts for the footer, except the links here are to external JS.

But a few of my sites I need to use a specific CSS and JS, that I did not implement yet. If I include that in the header, it means that all my pages are loading an external CSS or JS file, which I dont think is so good?

Is there a way I can only call a script on a few pages, without setting it in my header.html or footer.html?

header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="resources/library/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">               <!-- ok -->
        <link href="assets/css/core/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">                                   <!-- ok -->
        <link href="resources/library/bootstrap/bootstrap-reset.css" rel="stylesheet">             <!-- ok -->
        <!-- <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

        <!--external css-->
        <link href="assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />            <!-- ok -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/library/flexslider/css/flexslider.css"/>           <!-- ok -->
        <link href="resources/library/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />            <!-- ok -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/core/animate.css">                                 <!-- ok -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/library/owlcarousel/css/owl.carousel.css">          <!-- ok -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/library/owlcarousel/css/owl.theme.css">             <!-- ok -->

        <link href="resources/library/superfish/css/superfish.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> <!-- ok -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!-- <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->


        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/core/component.css">                     <!-- ok -->
        <link href="assets/css/core/style.css" rel="stylesheet">                                        <!-- ok -->
        <link href="assets/css/core/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />                           <!-- ok -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/library/parallax-slider/css/parallax-slider.css" />     <!-- ok -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/library/parallax-slider/js/modernizr.custom.28468.js"></script>  <!-- ok -->
</head>

index.php
<body>
  <p> A lot of content</p>



<?php include 'resources/includes/footer.html';?>
```

footer.html

```
<div>
  <div>
   <p> A lot of content</p>
  </div>
</div>

    **<!-- *********  The Magnific popup script I only use on 2 sites:  *********-->**
    <script src="js/module/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>

    <!-- Scripts for all sites -->
    <script src="resources/library/bootstrap/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>                              <!-- ok -->
        <script src="resources/library/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>                                 <!-- ok -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/library/superfish/js/hover-dropdown.js"></script>      <!-- ok -->
        <script defer src="resources/library/flexslider/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>                   <!-- ok -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/library/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>         <!-- ok -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/library/parallax-slider/js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>   <!-- ok -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.image-caption a').tooltip();

    $(function () {

        var filterList = {

            init: function () {

                // MixItUp plugin
                // http://mixitup.io
                $('#portfoliolist-three').mixitup({
                    targetSelector: '.portfolio',
                    filterSelector: '.filter',
                    effects: ['fade'],
                    easing: 'snap',
                    // call the hover effect
                    onMixEnd: filterList.hoverEffect()
                });

            },

        };

        // Run the show!
        filterList.init();


    });

    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $('.magnefig').each(function(){
            $(this).magnificPopup({
                    type:'image',
                    removalDelay: 300,
                    mainClass: 'mfp-fade'
               })
        });
    });
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Example:**

These two links I need on 1 side. Where should those to links be placed?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/module/mixitup.css"> <!-- ok -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/module/magnific-popup.css"> <!-- ok -->
```

Comment: Either include those files on the individual pages that need them, or create an alternate header and footer that are included on those pages (and pull the 'special' files) and use those instead of the standard header and footer.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. If I just place them on my individual pages, where should I place the links? I have just edited my question with an example. I cannot see how it is working out if I post them on the individual sites:-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way in core php use include in your custom pages to add header and footer. To add extra css add in content pages

index.php without extra css

```
include('header.php');

<div>
content goes here
</div>

include('footer.php');
```

about.php with extra css

```
include('header.php');
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/module/mixitup.css"> <!-- ok -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/module/magnific-popup.css"> <!-- ok -->
<div>
content goes here
</div>

include('footer.php');
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually thought it was bad standard to do like that, but cool I will do that :)